# Umbraco local + Umbraco cloud missing dlls (ucommerce)

Tags: umbraco, umbraco-ucommerce, umbraco-cloud

I have an issue with Umbraco Cloud and installing packages - specifically syncing local and cloud environments after installation.

It doesn't seem to matter whether I set up everything in the cloud version first or my local version - when I push/pull the changes the environment getting the updates will complain of missing dlls

Currently I have set up ucommerce in the cloud (installed via package) and pulled this to a fresh local copy - when I try to run the site I get:

Could not convert string 'UCommerce.RavenDB25.Search.SearchLibraryInternalRaven, UCommerce.RavenDB25' to a type. Assembly was not found. Make sure it was deployed and the name was not mistyped.

Checking this, my local version of the RavenDB25 folder doesn't contain the SearchLibraryInternalRaven dll or any other for that matter.

Can I view the file structure of my app in Umbraco Cloud? could this be a git ignore issue? I notice this in the default gitignore:

bin/NativeBinaries/*

Answer (score 1):

Something in the gitignore was omitting the ucommerce dlls (bin folder) a manual copy over fixed it

Answer (score 0):

You can view files of Umbraco Cloud. First log in to your project. Then go to Kudu tool:
[image]

Go to CMD
[image]

You can check dll files at site/wwwroot/bin